# Як створити багато таблиць в одній моделі.Django

Tags: django

В нас є модель пацієнта
Class Patient(models.Model):
В цій моделі лежать данні про пацієнта.
Модель всіх електронних медичних карток
Class Cards(models.Model):
В цій моделі зберігається список всіх електронних медичних карток
(id,card_name,card_user)
Модель однієї картки 
Class Card(models.Model)
В цій моделі зберігаються записи картки
(Id,запис)
У кожного користувача має бути своя таблиця моделі Card

Як автоматично створювати ці таблиці.

Answer (score 1):

Пишите модели с нужнми полями, [согласно документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/), а потом запукаете `./manage.py makemigrations` и `./manage.py migrate` . Это АЗЫ разработки на Django. Незнание таких моментов говорит о том, что вы не читали документацию, а это в свою очередь понижает ваши шансы получить ответ.

Что касается несколько таблиц в одной модели - это бессмысленно и невозможно. Только если наследованием.

В django каждая сущность - модель. Даже отличия сущностей можно разделить на модели (пример - модель транспорт, и модель мотоцикл и машина со своими доп полями)